# How to convert RGB to rgb color code

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

How can i get this color in rgb mode?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\definecolor{tl1}{RGB}{214,216,220}
\definecolor{o1}{RGB}{86,73,93}
\tikzset{bl1/.style={upper left=tl1,upper right=o1,lower left=o1,lower right=o1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[block_1/.style={draw,rectangle,minimum width=19mm,minimum
    height = 10mm, line width=0.5pt,rounded corners=1pt,draw=gray,drop shadow}]
 \node[block_1,bl1,text=white,font=\sffamily\tiny]{MAPER};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Divide the entries by 255. Somehow this plot looks *very* familiar to me.

Comment: Thank You, that's it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rule for the conversion is just to divide the entries by 255. However, `xcolor` can do that for you. For instance,

```
 \convertcolorspec{RGB}{214,216,220}{rgb}\tmptl
```

converts the RGB code to the corresponding rgb code, and stores the result in `\tmptl`. The colors match, as they should.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadings,shadows}
\definecolor{TL1}{RGB}{214,216,220}
\definecolor{O1}{RGB}{86,73,93}
\convertcolorspec{RGB}{214,216,220}{rgb}\tmptl
\definecolor{tl1}{rgb}\tmptl
\convertcolorspec{RGB}{86,73,93}{rgb}\tmpo
\definecolor{o1}{rgb}\tmpo
\tikzset{bl1/.style={upper left=tl1,upper right=o1,lower left=o1,lower right=o1}}
\tikzset{BL1/.style={upper left=TL1,upper right=O1,lower left=O1,lower right=O1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[block_1/.style={draw,rectangle,minimum width=19mm,minimum
    height = 10mm, line width=0.5pt,rounded corners=1pt,draw=gray,drop shadow}]
 \node[block_1,bl1,text=white,font=\sffamily\tiny](m){MAPER};
 \node[block_1,right=of m,BL1,text=white,font=\sffamily\tiny](M){MAPER};
 \node[below=of M,align=right,font=\sffamily]{%
 top left: $\{r,g,b\}=\{\tmptl\}$\\
 other: $\{r,g,b\}=\{\tmpo\}$\\
 };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The shading on the left is with the RGB colors whereas on the right it is the rgb colors that resulted from the conversion.

Comment: Thank you, also works conversation => RBG/255 = rgb